# JavaScript language query around Backbone.js _bindRoutes method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've been looking through the Backbone.js source, and I'm a little confused as to how the [_bindRoutes method in Backbone.Router](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-86) actually works.

When you create a set of routes, the ordering is of course very important:

```
routes: {
   "blah", "checkFirst",
   "blah2", "checkSecond",
   "*anything", "ifNothingElseMatches"
}
```

However the code in `_bindRoutes`, seems to pull out the specified routes simply with a `for in` loop over the `routes` object.

This would potentially pull the results out in an un-ordered fashion (*"There is no guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular order" - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)*).

Am I missing something? As I can't see how you can trust the route priority order if the above is all true.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you think ordering is important? The order in the routes object is not important. As you mentioned, there is no order in litteral objects.

If you look at the Backbone doc for Routers (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router) you'll see that the routes is association of urls and functions.

> You'll want to define actions that are triggered when certain URL fragments are matched, and provide a routes hash that pairs routes to actions.

In your example, when I'll go to www.your_site.com/your_page#blah2 it will execute the checkSecond function in the Backbone Router.

So, as there is no order in the routes, you have to guide the user through routing.
You can redirect user by using the navigate function :

```
router.navigate("blah", true)
```

Comment: The reason for believing that the order is important is that in other routing systems (e.g. ASP.NET MVC) you have a top down approach, meaning that you can have a 'catch-all' route at the bottom of the list for example.

Comment: This is an oversimplification. Order is important if you want it to be. One common use case in rails is a catchall route, to support that in backbone, you need to do something along the lines of passing an array with your routes in order as objects or two item subarrays, and then traversing that in reverse and calling `router.route(<route>, <name>, <handler>)` explicitly .. see marionette's [AppRouter](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.approuter.js)

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee in the language specification (and that [isn't changing with ES5](http://es5.github.com/x12.html#x12.6.4) - *"The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties ... is not specified"*), but the *de facto* standard is for `for..in` iteration to give you properties in definition/insertion order.

Since the behaviour isn't specified, implementations are technically free to do what they want, giving you bug reports like [Chromium Issue 164](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164) when one of them differs from the others, in this case because Chrome treats numeric properties differently.